# “Cartesian” dual vs. polar dual of convex polytope

Tags: geometry

Say $P$ is a convex Euclidean polytope, where the origin is not contained in any bounding hyperplane containing a facet of $P$, with $n$ facets given by $\langle f_i , x\rangle = 1$ and $m$ vertices $v_j$ with $1\leq i\leq n$ and $1\leq j\leq m$. (That is, each facet equation has been multiplied through as needed to obtain $1$ on the right side.)
Is it true that the polytope $P’$ with $m$ facets given by $\langle v_j , x\rangle = 1$ and $n$ vertices $f_i$ is combinatorially equivalent to the polar dual $P^*$ of $P$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Your polytope $P'$ is exactly the polar $P^*$ of $P$ with respect to the standard unit sphere. Choosing another conic instead of the unit sphere will in general give another polar. See [this wikpedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_and_polar) for the two-dimensional case of polarity with respect to other conics. So your "Cartesian" dual corresponds to the unit sphere.

Polarity/duality of polytopes or more generally, convex bodies, is treated in many books on convexity. Unfortunately, many of them leave a lot of detail to the reader. I recommend [Webster's *Convexity*](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=SWQmykCwabwC&lpg=PP1&dq=webster%20convexity&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false), [Brønsted's *An Introduction to Convex Polytopes*](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=rvrYsRREzSYC&lpg=PA56&dq=polar%20of%20polytope&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q=polar%20of%20polytope&f=false) or [Matousek's *Lectures on Discrete Geometry*](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=dH5DK1URwQgC&lpg=PP1&dq=matousek&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q=matousek&f=false).

Comment: Thanks! I will check out these references. I omitted from the question whether P is fully dimensional - i.e., a d-dimensional polytope in R^d. If P is k-dimensional (k < d) in R^d, and P is contained in a k-dimensional hyperplane, then the facet equations for P are not uniquely determined - so the Cartesian dual would depend on the choice of these equations as well. (I'm ditching the scare quotes, and the pun is intended.)